# Copying Files By LastWriteTime

Tags: c#

I have hit a brick wall! My objective is to copy files between two folders only on a given day, disregarding files in the same folder with an earlier LastWriteTime. My logic seems to work, however I receive an exception when running the code which states it cannot find my test file, even though it wouldn't be able to tell me the name of my test files if it didn't work!! :( I have posted my code below, please help!

```
namespace RunAfterFirstScan
{
    class Program
    {

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetNewest(string path)
    {
        DateTime to_date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5);
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        if (!directoryInfo.Exists) return Enumerable.Empty<string>();

        var query =
            from file in directoryInfo.GetFiles()
            where file.LastWriteTime.Date == to_date.Date          
            select file.Name;

        return query;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string sourcePath = @"C:\Users\berryn01\Desktop\From\";
        string targetPath = @"C:\Users\berryn01\Desktop\To\";

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }


        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            string[] files = GetNewest(sourcePath).ToArray();
            foreach (string s in files)
            {

                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which part is not working. Is there any exception or error ? Elaborate your question.

Comment: If your file is created today, it will never be found, because you substract 5 days in your GetNewest method. Also, I think that comparison `file.LastWriteTime.Date == to_date.Date` is a mistake, and should be `file.LastWriteTime.Date >= to_date.Date`

Comment: Sorry, to elaborate, there is an exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not find file 'Opinion Set Routine.docx'.  I'm not so much worried about the date, as I was just using the subtraction to test files in the folder created earlier. Each time I change this value however, it finds the correct file on that given date then throws an exception saying it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. I think it must be `>=` or `<=` according to your need.

```
var query =
            from file in directoryInfo.GetFiles()
            where file.LastWriteTime.Date <= to_date.Date
            select file.Name;
```

**OR**

```
var query =
            from file in directoryInfo.GetFiles()
            where file.LastWriteTime.Date >= to_date.Date
            select file.Name;
```

Comment: Ok, I have changed the query to '>=' but receive the same exception. Let's say I have files created today in the folder, and run it with 'DateTime to_date = DateTime.Today' I will be thrown the exception, but if I go back a day and it finds nothing the code executes fine. It seems to me it is finding the file properly, then somehow not using the full path when running the copy method? I'm not sure, I am at a loss there.

Comment: Sorry for my formatting by the way, just learning the rules of the road here.

Comment: The best I can figure, by the time I call `System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile);` it no longer knows the source path and just has the file name. Any idea how I can reformat with that in mind?

Comment: Problem Solved!!! It turns out I needed to recombine my path with my filename, since my GetNewest method was stripping off just the file name. I edited my foreach to include:


    `string srcFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, s);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, s);
    System.IO.File.Copy(srcFile, destFile);`

and voila!

Thank you for all of the help!

I hope this might help someone in the future.